# Understanding MySQL log_queries_not_using_indexes behavior

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

I wanted to check if my server's queries are properly using index. So I enabled `log_queries_not_using_indexes`, and ran test-cases.

I found out that the following query is written on `mysql.slow_log` table.

```
SELECT * FROM user_rel 
WHERE (f = '5837be9dc34f747dbd7ba6c7' AND t = '5837be9dc34f747dbd7ba6ca') 
OR (f = '5837be9dc34f747dbd7ba6ca' AND t = '5837be9dc34f747dbd7ba6c7') 
LIMIT 2;
```

But my `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` result seems ok.

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'user_rel', 'range', 'f-t-UNIQUE,t_uid_idx', 'f-t-UNIQUE', '208', NULL, '2', '100.00', 'Using index condition'
```

Please someone can explain me why this query is written as `slow_log`?

---

**Edit 1**

Here are mysql options regarding slow query logging.

```
log_output  TABLE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   ON
long_query_time 2.000000
min_examined_row_limit  0
slow_query_log  ON
sql_log_off OFF
```

---

**Edit 2**

After I updated `min_examined_row_limit` to `10`, the query doesn't show up anymore. But why is this affect the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` result?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... smells like another reason to avoid `log_queries_not_using_indexes`.

If `f` and `t` are symmetric:

The table would be more efficiently queried if you 'sorted' the two columns before storing them.  You would not need to do the `OR` and it could more efficiently use the obvious index.

Comment: So you're suggesting keeping only one row for unique `f`, `t` pair. I'll try to refactor as you suggest. Thank you.